# Testing mail verification in organization domain

Tags: selenium-webdriver, email

**Requirement:**

Users should sign up for an application using mail id and an email will be triggered to that mail account. Mail will have the verification link , once the user verifies he can onboard into the app

**Email restriction:**

Should be of Organization domain ( gmail / outlook / 3rd party mailboxes cannot be used)

**Current manual flow:**

We are creating org mail accounts, using temp mail providers and using that to sign up.

**Question:**

What is the best way to automate this requirement? Please suggest tools, APIs and other relevant inputs

Comment: When you say "organization domain" what exactly do you mean? Do you mean the email addresses have to belong to a specific domain such as the one belonging to your employer, or that they can't be from any of the free email providers?

Comment: Yeah that's right, email domain should be that org domain